# Parsing json data with jquery eval

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

My source code:

```
function getdata()
{$(document).ready(function(){
$('#data').load('getdata.php');

jsonStatus=eval("("+reqIntiAjax.responseText+")");

});
}
setInterval("getdata()",300);
```

my data:
[{"data1":1,"data2":4}]

how to decode json data with jquery?
im using getdata=eval("("+reqIntiAjax.responseText+")"); its not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.getJSON` to have jQuery automatically parse the JSON for you, or use `JSON.parse` to decode the JSON yourself. There is absolutely no reason to use `eval` for this.